# javascript program to convert binary to decimal and back

Tags: javascript

I have tried this

```
function binToDec(num) {
    let dec = 0; 
    for(let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if(num[num.length - (i + 1)] === '1') {
            dec += 2 ** i;
        }
    }
    return dec;
}

console.log(binToDec('1010'));
```

this code is not mine and it works but i want to know how it converts the binary number to decimal and it will be very helpful is you could tell me another way to do it.

I have also tried this

```
function binToDec(num) {
    let bin = parseInt(num, 2);
    return bin;
}
console.log(binToDec(1010));
```

I know this also work but i am not looking for this answer.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just starts with the last character of the string and adds the value of this position to the result.

> ```
> string    dec
> ------  -------
>  1010    0
>     0    0
>    1     0 + 2
>   0      2
>  1       2 + 8
> ------  ------
>         10
> ```

```js
function binToDec(num) {
    let dec = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (num[num.length - (i + 1)] === '1') {
            dec += 2 ** i;
        }
    }
    return dec;
}

console.log(binToDec('1010')); // 10
```

Another way is to start with the left side of the sting and

- multiply the converted value by the base (2) and
- add the value of the string.

The result is now the converted number. This works for all bases, as long as the value at the index is converted to a number.

```js
function binToDec(num) {
    let dec = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        dec *= 2;
        dec += +num[i];
    }
    return dec;
}

console.log(binToDec('1101')); // 13
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but it is possible log the number as number instead of string and still return true because when i change '1010' to 1010 it return 0

Comment: which `true` do you want? and where?

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Think of how base 10 works.

```
909 = 900 + 9
    = (9 *   100) + (0 *    10) + (9 *     1)
    = (9 * 10**2) + (0 * 10**1) + (9 * 10**0)
```

As you can see, a natural number in base 10 can be seen as a sum where each term is in the form of:

```
digit * base**digit_position
```

This is true for any base:

```
base 2 : 0b101 = (0b1 * 2**2) + (0b0 * 2**1) + (0b1 * 2**0)
base 16 : 0xF0F = (0xF * 16**2) + (0x0 * 16**1) + (0xF * 16**0)
```

Therefore, here is a possible abstraction of a natural number:

```
function natural_number (base, digits) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    digit = digits[i];
    digit_position = digits.length - (i + 1);
    sum += digit * base**digit_position;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

```
> | natural_number(2, [1, 0, 1]) // 1 * 2**2 + 1 * 2**0
< | 5
> | natural_number(10, [1, 0, 1]) // 1 * 10**2 + 1 * 10**0
< | 101
> | natural_number(16, [1, 0, 1]) // 1 * 16**2 + 1 * 16**0
< | 257
```

Your own function takes only binary numbers (base 2). In this case `digit` can be either 0 or 1, that's all. We know that it's useless to multiply something by 0 or 1, so the addition can be replaced with:

```
if (digit === 1) {
  sum += 2**digit_position;
}
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
if (num[num.length - (i + 1)] === '1') {
  dec += 2 ** i;
}
```

Do you get it? :-)

### Alternative

You don't feel confortable with the exponentiation operator (`**`)? There is a workaround. Did you ever notice that multiplying a number by 10 is nothing more than shifting its digits one time to the left?

```
909 * 10 = 9090
```

Actually, shifting a number to the left boils down to multiplying this number by its base:

```
number *= base
```

This is true for any base:

```
base 2 : 0b11 * 2 = 0b110
base 16 : 0xBEE * 16 + 0xF = 0xBEE0 + 0xF = 0xBEEF
```

Based on this, we can build an algorithm to convert an array of digits into a number. A trace of execution with `[9,0,9]` in base 10 as input would look like this:

```
init  |   0 | n = 0
add 9 |   9 | n += 9
shift |  90 | n *= 10
add 0 |  90 | n += 0
shift | 900 | n *= 10
add 9 | 909 | n += 9
```

Here is a possible implementation:

```
function natural_number (base, digits) {
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    n += digits[i];
    if (i + 1 < digits.length) {
      n *= base;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

Of course this function works the same as before, and there is a good reason for that. Indeed, unroll the `for` loop that computes `[9,0,9]` in base 10, you get this:

```
return ((0 + 9) * 10 + 0) * 10 + 9;
```

Then expand this expression:

```
((0 + 9) * 10 + 0) * 10 + 9
= (0 + 9) * 10 * 10 + 0 * 10 + 9
= 9 * 10 * 10 + 0 * 10 + 9
= 9 * 10**2 + 0 * 10**1 + 9 * 10**0
```

Do you recognize the equation discussed earlier? :-)

### Bonus

Reverse function:

```
function explode_natural_number (base, number) {
  var remainder, exploded = [];
  while (number) {
    remainder = number % base;
    exploded.unshift(remainder);
    number = (number - remainder) / base;
  }
  return exploded.length ? exploded : [0];
}
```

```
> | explode_natural_number(2, 5)
< | [1, 0, 1]
> | explode_natural_number(3, 5) // base 3 (5 = 1 * 3**1 + 2 * 3**0) :-)
< | [1, 2]
> | explode_natural_number(16, natural_number(16, [11, 14, 14, 15])) // 0xBEEF
< | [11, 14, 14, 15]
```

String to number and number to string:

```
function parse_natural_number (number, base) {
  var ZERO = 48, A = 65; // ASCII codes
  return natural_number(base, number.split("").map(function (digit) {
    return digit.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
  }).map(function (code) {
    return code - (code < A ? ZERO : A - 10);
  }));
}

function stringify_natural_number (number, base) {
  var ZERO = 48, A = 65; // ASCII codes
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(
    String, explode_natural_number(base, number).map(function (digit) {
      return digit + (digit < 10 ? ZERO : A - 10);
    })
  );
}
```

```
> | stringify_natural_number(parse_natural_number("48879", 10), 16)
< | "BEEF"
> | parse_natural_number("10", 8)
< | 8
```

More levels of abstraction for convenience:

```
function bin_to_dec (number) {
  return parse_natural_number(number, 2);
}

function oct_to_dec (number) {
  return parse_natural_number(number, 8);
}

function dec_to_dec (number) {
  return parse_natural_number(number, 10);
}

function hex_to_dec (number) {
  return parse_natural_number(number, 16);
}

function num_to_dec (number) {
  switch (number[0] + number[1]) {
    case "0b" : return bin_to_dec(number.slice(2));
    case "0x" : return hex_to_dec(number.slice(2));
    default : switch (number[0]) {
      case "0" : return oct_to_dec(number.slice(1));
      default : return dec_to_dec(number);
    }
  }
}
```

```
> | oct_to_dec("10")
< | 8
> | num_to_dec("010")
< | 8
> | 010 // :-)
< | 8
```

```
function dec_to_bin (number) {
  return stringify_natural_number(number, 2);
}
```

```
> | dec_to_bin(8)
< | "1000"
```